# Local storage remove item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I'm trying to make simple ToDo list using JQuery and I tried to implement locaStorage (it's my first time using it) into it. Adding elements to localStorage works fine, but i'm having problems with deleting them. I've tried this:

```
localStorage.removeItem("todolist", $('#todoList').html());
```

and this:

```
localStorage.removeItem("todolist");
```

in both cases when I use delete button, all of mine 'li' elements are deleted, but I want to delete individual element 'li' ,so could I use something like 'this' selector in JQuery. Here is mine JSBin so you better understand what I'm doing: http://jsbin.com/tenara/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Can you post more codes please.

Comment: Dont store the `html` in local storage, store an array of objects (stringified) and add/remove from it as todo list items are added/removed

Comment: Note that localstorage only stores a string, so when you want to delete specific elements, you have to parse and reapply it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you remove an item, you aren't deleting your entire `todolist`. Rather, you should save the updated `todolist` with that item removed.

While your method of saving the items is questionable (you should really have an array of items, each item having a description and a "done" state, then JSON stringify it and save that instead), it should work just fine, provided you actually save the updated list when an item is removed.

Comment: So basically I need to update my list when I press delete button ? Should I do that in mine function for deleting list items or when document is ready ?  I'm sorry i'm total beginner in programming and grasping all these new concepts is hard for me. At first I tried making this List with JSON but that didn't go well, so now I'm trying to achieve it with localStorage.